# Kafka producer disabling

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I have an app that consumes one Kafka topic, doing things, and produces the result into two different topics.

The tricky thing is that the outgoing topic may not exist yet and I need to have an opportunity to switch off the producer on demand by environment varieable.

I can disable send() method this way, but at app startup it tries to connect to the topic to get metadata and spams:

`Error while fetching metadata ... UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION`

Tried different producer-properties but with no luck. Also tried to annotate producer class with ConditionalOnProperty, but the bean is required by service class.

Comment: Did you try setting spring: `kafka.listener.missing-topics-fatal=false` in properties?

Comment: Forgot to mention that i am using **Spring Cloud Stream** framefork, so no such property here, unfortunately

Comment: This property is provided at the boot level and you can use this in your SCSt app. But more importantly, `SCSt` uses Spring for Apache Kafka underneath, and therefore all Spring Kafka properties are applicable for a Spring Cloud Stream application as well.

Comment: Tried that setting, but it showed no effect. Still getting the same warnings when the app tries to connect to the topic

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default producers and consumers are started automatically. You can disable it using `auto-startup` Consumer/Producer properties - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.5/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_producer_properties.

You can also start/stop bindings via actuator REST endpoints - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.5/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding_visualization_control

Comment: Trying te set it in application.yml but getting "The configuration "auto-startup" was supplied but isn't a known config."
`spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          producer-properties:
            auto-startup: false`

Comment: You missing binding name. There is an example there - `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.func-out-0.producer.auto-startup=false`, where `func-out-0` corresponds to a binding name for the output.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not make any change, still getting 
`Error while fetching metadata ... UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION`

Comment: Actually there is more interesting behaviour: I tried to set **auto-startup=false** for the consumer, and it stopped receiving messages from topic. But as soon as i delete the topic the app is getting UnknownTopicOrPartitionException. 
So it looks like even if you **switch OFF** the consumer or producer, it tries to establish connection anyway.

Comment: Connection and producing/consuming messages are to different things, so what you're describing is the expected behavior.

Comment: Is there a way to turn off connection as well?

Comment: It's going to keep retrying which is one of the features in case connection issues. I don't know your use case, but  understand that spring-cloud-stream is not a general purpose messaging framework and is designed for specific use cases in mind which may not be what you're looking for. This means you can go one step back and use spring-integration (core building block for spring-cloud-stream) directly.framework directly - https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanations!